# Problems between Powerpoint 2010 on Windows 7 and 2003 on Windows XP

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, microsoft-powerpoint

We have an employee who creates ppt's on her home computer using PowerPoint 2010 on Windows 7. At work she has Powerpoint 2003 with the compatibility pack on XP. The ppt she creates at home will open at work, but when she tries to do anything - move a text box, enter text, add graphics - it hangs and she has to use task manager to kill PowerPoint. To make things more confusing, a colleague has PowerPoint 2003 with the compatibility pack on Windows 7. She can open the ppt and edit it with no problems. She can't save it down to 2003 because of group policies.

I am at a loss. Apparently there is something that is in Windows 7 missing in XP, but I can't figure out what, or how to get the ppt to work on the original employees computer.

Comment: Has the employee tried saving it as ppt 97-2003 instead of just saving as 2010 at her home? That would avoid the compatibility pack on XP and might work without much problems on any system.

Comment: That is one solution, and may be what we have to go with. If possible, I would like to understand what causes the 2010 file to work with 2003 under Windows 7, but not XP, even if we can't actually fix it.

Comment: Any chance that she's using PPT/Windows under Bootcamp/Parallels/Fusion/Etc on a Mac?